# Sum the values of two 2d arrays based on shared key paths

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, mapping

I have two arrays with this structure

```
array1 = Array(0=>Array(4, 7, 0, 11), 1=> Array(5,7,6,18));
array2 = Array(0=>Array(5,1,7,13), 1=>Array(9,1,6,16));
```

I tried to calculate sum of this array by element like this `=> 4 + 5 = 9;`

```
Array(0=>Array(9,8,7,24), 1=>Array(14, 8, 12, 34));
```

Comment: [array_sum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) might help

Comment: Can you add  exactly the input you have and the output you'd want? as @JakeGould said this is a bit confusing

Comment: So which values in which of the two arrays do you want summing? If you can't explain the problem clearly, it's not easy for us to provide a solution

Comment: I want to calculate sum per column, in the exempla above from array 1 extract element from first sub array, 4 and the same with array2, 5 and save into array

Comment: Eg:
$array1 = Array(0 => Array(1,3), 1=>Array(5,7));
$array2 = Array(0 => Array(2,4), 1=>Array(10,2));

I want to calculate sum between this two array and the result might be $result = array(0=>Array(3, 7), 1=>Array(15,9))

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$array1 = [[4, 7, 0, 11], [5, 7, 6, 18]];
$array2 = [[5, 1, 7, 13], [9, 1, 6, 16]];

$output = array_map(function($a, $b){
    return array_map(function() {
        return array_sum(func_get_args());
    }, $a, $b);
}, $array1, $array2);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 9
      1 => int 8
      2 => int 7
      3 => int 24
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 14
      1 => int 8
      2 => int 12
      3 => int 34
```